# Naming relationships changes the results?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

Consider both queries:

```
[1]
MATCH (p1:Person)-[ACTED_IN]->(m1:Movie), (p2:Person)-[DIRECTED]->(m1)
WHERE p1 = p2
RETURN p1.name

[2]
MATCH (p1:Person)-[xa:ACTED_IN]->(m1:Movie), (p2:Person)-[xd:DIRECTED]->(m1)
WHERE p1 = p2
RETURN p1.name
```

The only difference is `xa:` and `xd:`, the relationship aliases.

The difference in result is much bigger:

- Query 1 has 32 rows. Every person has at least 2 rows, some have 6.
- Query 2 has  3 rows. All 3 are different.
- Aliasing 1 XOR the other has even different results: 4 or 10 rows.

Why? There's no aggregation. The relationship aliases are unused. Why does it change the query?

Database is free example db 'Movie graph' on https://app.graphenedb.com/ (but it's private).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've mixed up the syntax of what differentiates a variable from a relationship type. In your first match, because there is no `:` character, `ACTED_IN` and `DIRECTED` are *variables*, matching to any relationship type, and throwing off your matched results.

`:ACTED_IN` and `:DIRECTED` are what you meant to use, because the prefixed `:` denotes them as relationship types.

It works the same way with node labels and variables, with a token prefixed by `:` indicating a node label, and the token before the colon used as an variable (or if no `:` is present, there is no label and the entire thing is an variable).

EDIT

Here are a few examples of relationship syntax, pointing out the relevant parts:

In this one, ACTED_IN is a variable for all relationships between p1 and m1.

```
(p1:Person)-[ACTED_IN]->(m1:Movie)
```

In this one, :ACTED_IN is the relationship type between p1 and m1, and no variable is present

```
(p1:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m1:Movie)
```

In this one, :ACTED_IN is the relationship type between p1 and m1, and 'a' is the variable bound to the matched relationships.

```
(p1:Person)-[a:ACTED_IN]->(m1:Movie)
```

This one is invalid syntax, since there must be a token after the `:` to act as the relationship type.

```
(p1:Person)-[a:]->(m1:Movie)
```

Comment: That's what I thought, but it says `-[x:]->` is invalid syntax (for 'any relationship type AS x`). Can I alias the 'any relationship' ?

Comment: `-[x:]->` is invalid because the `:` must prefix the variable type, if present. `-[:x]->` is a relationship of type 'x' with no alias. `-[x]->` has no type, and will match relationships of any type and bind them to an alias of 'x'.

Comment: Ah, that's how that works! I can't find help on syntax like that anywhere. Is it 'graphdb' or 'neo4j' or 'cypher'?

Comment: This is Cypher syntax, and Neo4j is the primary db that uses this. The [Neo4j developer manual](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/) will probably be the most helpful for you. Here's the section on [relationships](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#_describing_relationships). Here's a [Cypher reference card](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-refcard/current/) that's handy to keep around.

Comment: Also, I goofed in my terminology. In Cypher, an alias refers to aliasing columns in WITH and RETURN, such as `RETURN rels AS relationships`. The terminology for what we've been talking about is around variables for relationships or nodes. I've fixed the terminology in my answer accordingly.